# What does "Empty print file" mean and how can I diagnose it?

Tags: linux, printing

When trying to print I get this error. What does it mean? How can I diagnose it?

Comment: You don't give enough information to get a meaningful answer. Generally speaking, you need to give enough detail for someone to be able reproduce your attempt. Does it happen in a particular program or everywhere? only with a particular file or all the time? How did you configure printing?

Comment: I asked because a simple search didn't return useful results on how to investigate the problem. I've clarified the question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question can't be simply answered.
It usually means that something with your printing device driver is messed up.

Any additional information?

Most likely you are using CUPS.

Did you have a look at the logfiles? /var/log/cups/ ?

Maybe this will help you, to specify your questions.

Try to do some printing at a low level to eliminate any error sources with some applications. Have a read through the manual: http://www.cups.org/documentation.php especially at "Command Line Printing" http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.4/options.html

This will give you some basic diagnostic tools.

Comment: Excellent. I struggled to find any explanation for this error message, and wanted confirmation that it is a generic and not-terribly-useful message. Thanks for the diagnostic links! I have clarified the question to this end.